# Using PolynomialFeatures and LinearRegression to plot predicting line of n-degree not working properly as n > 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

For MRE:

```
m = 100
X = 6*np.random.rand(m,1)-3
y = 0.5*X**2 + X+2 + np.random.randn(m,1)

lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(X,y)
y_pred_1 = lin_reg.predict(X)
y_pred_1 = [_[0] for _ in y_pred_1]
```

Plotting (X,y) on the graph works fine. Plotting (X, y_pred_1) gives me a line of best fit. Now since my y value above is created using X to the power of 2 thus it would look like a parabola.

So best fitting line would not be linear in this case but polynomaial with degree 2.

So I do:

```
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2, include_bias=False)
X_poly_2 = poly_features.fit_transform(X)

poly_reg_2 = LinearRegression()
poly_reg_2.fit(X_poly_2, y)

y_pred_2 = poly_reg_2.predict(X_poly_2)
y_pred_2 = [_[0] for _ in y_pred_2]
```

and plot it on my graph which gives me something like a parabola but contains too much line. here is what I get when I plot points, predicting line of 1-degree, prediction line of 2-degree.

Using ploty:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
plot_X = [_[0] for _ in X.tolist()]
plot_y = [_[0] for _ in y.tolist()]

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = plot_X,
        y = plot_y,
        mode="markers"
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = plot_X,
        y = y_pred_1,
        name="degree = 1"
    )
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = plot_X,
        y = y_pred_2,
        name="degree = 2"
    )
)

fig.show()
```

which outputs [image]

What am I doing wrong?

Out of curiosity why does sklearn use linear regression to predict non-linear things like parabola in my case?

Also if I run 
`poly_reg_2.coef_` it gives me `array([[0.99366804, 0.45225746]])` how would I interpret this?

`y = 0.99366804x + 0.45225746x` was what I've thought but then it would not draw parabola how do you know which coefficient to raise to a power of 2 and which one to keep it degree =1?

EDIT: when I plot using

```
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x = plot_X,
        y = y_pred_2,
        name="degree = 2",
        mode="markers"
    )
)
```

adding mode parameter and setting it to marker which creates a scatterplot it seems to show work fine but in scatterplot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
This is my way to solve it.

```
x_predict = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y_predict = lin_reg.predict(poly_features.transform(x_predict .reshape(-1, 1)))
plt.plot(x_predict , y_predict)
plt.plot(X, y, 'bo')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have error in X_poly_2 before enter into the LR.
It seems X_poly_2 should be changed to

```
X_poly_2=X_poly_2[:,0].reshape(100,1)
```

Comment: Thanks but could you explain what it is doing? I've thought it changes to 100x1 matrix but some values seems to go missing.

Comment: Also it does not seem to work. When I to that before I fit my model it does not output anything on the graph

Comment: Could you compare X and X_poly_2, then you can get the difference.